# About Rote learning

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy

Has learning through doing repetitive exercises and mechanical non-creative exercises  been researched and analysed sufficiently for College and University level courses? Have there been surveys and polls for High school and University Level students about whether they appreciate these repetitive and uninspiring exercises for learning and if it helps them? Have any College level students indicated Repetitive and uninspiring often mechanical learning is tedious or monotonous and doesn't really explain that much?

Comment: This question isn't very answerable in its current form. Do you really mean graduate education here? What age are students are you interested in? Can you give an example of what kinds of things they are learning by rote?

Comment: "Rote learning" (to me) means "memorization through repetition." If memorization is the aim, sometimes learning by rote can help. But some aspects of mathematics require understanding. 
An example of rote learning might be noticing that students say "the limit goes to" and you correct them, repeatedly, by telling them "we say 'the limit *is* and not 'the limit goes to.'" But if students *understand* the concept of limit, they may understand that "the limit goes to" makes no sense, and stop using it. This aligns with mathematics as a sense-making activity rather than facts and procedures.

Comment: My comment above is meant to add to Chris', and demonstrate that there is a reason to consider what it is they are learning when you ask about rote learning.

Comment: As J P Burke says rote learning is good for memorizing but for understanding formulas or principles this requires more; so rote learning itself is not sufficient for higher learning' like University level. Yet many Math books I have seen have a lot of 'rote learning'-style exercises. A few books though have had the 'foresight' to include clever exercises were a student can figure out a principle seemingly on their own. Like that Moore Method of teaching I read about.

Comment: *Rote learning* can also mean "understanding through repetition" or, better yet, "understanding through repetition with variation."  I understand that this is one way to describe East Asian mathematics education.

Comment: But how do you promote understanding? Ask a student to do 100 similar questions then hope she or he understands? I found one or two fascinating explanations of the processes involved followed by some exercises that build on that fascination (or at least interest) is better than 100 or so similar exercises.

Comment: Has rote learning and any method similar to it been studied as a teaching method for college students and whether most students like these methods? What is the Moore Method of teaching advanced Math?

Comment: I am not quite sure about what is being asked in the original question; I am also not sure how the checked response could answer anything "about rote learning" considering that it begins, verbatim, **"Has it been studied? I don't know. Does it work? In my opinion, no."**

Comment: Could Edward de Bono's ( who started 'lateral thinking') methods be used to teach Math?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Has it been studied?  I don't know.

Does it work?

In my opinion, no.  I have taught kids that came from asia where their math was done by rote.
Their arithmetic skills were impressive, but when presented with a large number of new ideas they had trouble seeing how the pieces fit together, and were often at loose ends when faced with a new variation.

Is there a place for rote learning?  Yes.  Doing many problems.  This helps build facility with algorithms.

Comment: A great way to learn is trying to discover an important principle on ones own. Students could be given various clues about certain Lemmas and Theories that could be used to prove some important Theorem being 'sought' after ; the teacher could supply additional hints trying to get each student to 'discover' the Theory being 'chased'. Like a 'Treasure hunt' in Math. Is this like the Moore method?

Comment: In what is this answer rooted? The first four sentences ("Has it been studied? I don't know. Does it work? In my opinion, no.") do not inspire confidence...

Comment: I think there's room for improvement in this answer. For instance, by looking into whether any research has been done on the effectiveness of rote learning at tertiary level.